# Getting twilio parse error on what looks valid

Tags: xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

Twilio is getting the following as the body of the xml according to the debugger. It says there is a problem on line 2, that the xml is not well formed. I copied this straight of of the debugger page and an hoping that someone could tell me what's wrong with this.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
<Enqueue waitUrl="contactagent_2.php">myqueue</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

**Edit:**

I just got an email from Twilio support.

> Hi, Thanks for checking with us. I apologize the error message is
>   misleading. The error message is actually regarding what is returned
>   by the  (below):
>
> http://sonosmile.com/twilio/queue/contactagent_2.php

So, there wasn't anything wrong with the XML itself. Thanks Kevin for taking time to look it over.

Comment: Can you send your account sid to help at twilio dot com? We can investigate this further. Alternatively can you post the exact message the debugger gave you?

Comment: Or a URL we can use for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

OP answerers in edit above:

> I just got an email from Twilio support.
>
> Hi, Thanks for checking with us. I apologize the error message is
>   misleading. The error message is actually regarding what is returned
>   by the (below):
>
> http://sonosmile.com/twilio/queue/contactagent_2.php

TwiML Bins in the new [console](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/twiml-bins) will also tell you if you have valid [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) (xml).